# Pandas Groupby and sum with two variables-

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am doing a groupby and sum on two variables. The second variable is year and for my example, there are only two years (2015 and 2016). For the second row of the sum the first variable (an ID#) is now shown. How do I force it to show?

Code:

```
totals = df.groupby(by=['id', 'year'])['sales'].sum()
print(totals)
```

Output Sample:

```
1234567             2015             596407.81
                    2016            7224148.34
```

How do I get the second row to have the ID 1234567?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use parameter `as_index=False` in [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
totals = df.groupby(by=['id', 'year'], as_index=False)['sales'].sum()
print(totals)
```

Or [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
totals = df.groupby(by=['id', 'year'])['sales'].sum().reset_index()
print(totals)
```

Reason why dont see last value in first column is `MultiIndex`